# JScrollPane only vertical and resize content Horizontal

Tags: jscrollpane

I'm using the jre1.8.0_66, the newest JRE currently.

I've the following problem with my code. I've a jpanel with a BoxLayout(Y_AXIS) into a JScrollPane, and when I resize the window I want my BoxLayout width always fits to size as the space available.

**This are a few photos to explain better my problem:**

First problem appear when the messages reach the vertical space available, the scrollbars appears but... I prefer resize the panel a little to correct the horizontal size, to don't show the horizontal scrollbar, I only need the vertical bars to continue reading all messages.

It's not a real problem, because I can solve it with the policy of vertical scrollbars always. But if I can, I prefer don't show scrollbars always.

[Minor Problem: When the scroll Appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItaZF.jpg)

The real problem appear when I resize the window. If i make the window more bigger, all it's ok, but... when I make it little again, the horizontal size continue with the same size, and I can't resize it.

[Big Problem: Resize width when I do less wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag6tE.jpg)

I try a lot of things, with a listener to listen when a component is resized, but, I can't solve it.

**These are my classes:**

***MainView***

```
package view;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;

public class MainView extends JFrame{
    private JPanel content;
    private ScrollPaneColor scrollPane;

    public MainView() {
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        /*
         * Content Panel to scrollPane
         */
        content = new JPanel();
        content.setBackground(backgroundColor);
        content.setLayout(new BoxLayout(content, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        /*
         * scrollPane
         */
        scrollPane = new ScrollPaneColor(content, backgroundColor, grey);

        /*
         * Action Panel to add more content
         */
        JPanel actions = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(actions, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        actions.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        JButton btnAddBlue = new JButton("add Blue");
        btnAddBlue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                MessageFor blue = new MessageFor("This is just a test to see how the ScrollPane interacts with the view ", backgroundColor, paletteBlue);
                content.add(blue);
                content.updateUI();
            }
        });
        actions.add(btnAddBlue);

        JButton btnAddRed = new JButton("add Red");
        btnAddRed.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                MessageFor red = new MessageFor("This is just a test to see how the ScrollPane interacts with the view ", backgroundColor, paletteRed);
                content.add(red);
                content.updateUI();
            }
        });
        actions.add(btnAddRed);

        /*
         * Nothing important, only the Split Panel
         */
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panel,scrollPane);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(150);
        getContentPane().add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /*
         * Nothing important, only the Title Panel
         */
        JPanel title = new JPanel();
        getContentPane().add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("title of actions");
        title.add(lblNewLabel);
    }

    /*
     * Nothing important, only the MAIN to run the program.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MainView view = new MainView();
        view.setVisible(true);
        view.setSize(900, 450);
        view.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /*
     * Nothing important, only the PaletteColors and backgroundColor to decorate.
     */
    private PaletteColor grey = new PaletteColor(
            new Color(0xBFBFBF),
            new Color(0xD8D8D8), new Color(0xF2F2F2), new Color(0xFFFFFF),
            new Color(0xA5A5A5), new Color(0x7F7F7F),
            new Color(0x000000), new Color(0x000000), new Color(0xFFFFFF));

    private PaletteColor paletteRed = new PaletteColor(
            new Color(0xDA1F28),
            new Color(0xEB757B), new Color(0xF2A3A7), new Color(0xF8D1D3),
            new Color(0xA3171E), new Color(0x6D0F14),
            new Color(0xFFFFFF), new Color(0x000000), new Color(0xFFFFFF));

    private PaletteColor paletteBlue = new PaletteColor(
            new Color(0x4F81BD),
            new Color(0x95B3D7), new Color(0xB8CCE4), new Color(0xDBE5F1),
            new Color(0x366092), new Color(0x244061),
            new Color(0xFFFFFF), new Color(0x000000), new Color(0xFFFFFF));

    private Color backgroundColor = Color.WHITE; 
}
```

***ScrollPaneColor*** This is the ScrollPane that don't work as I want. I only want Vertical scroll, not Horizontal. In this class I have a JPanel content, with a BoxLayout(Y_AXIS) defined into MainView to add things that I want to scroll vertically.

I try a lot of things to solve my problem, I do a listener to resize, and If I do setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER); I have a worst problem than now.

```
package view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

/**
 * Define a JScrollPane with the colors of the palette.
 * 
 * @author Jorge Dacal Cantos
 *
 */
public class ScrollPaneColor extends JScrollPane {
    private JPanel content;

    /**
     * Create a <code>JScrollPane</code> with scrollbars  as needed and
     * personal colors
     * 
     * @see #setViewportView
     * @param panel  The component to display in the scrollpane's viewport
     * @param background  The color for panel background.
     * @param palette  Palette with colors for scrollbars.
     * @author Jorge Dacal Cantos
     */ 
    public ScrollPaneColor(JPanel panel, Color background, PaletteColor palette) {
        super(panel);
        content = panel;
        setBackground(background);
        setBorder(null);
        //setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        //setScrollsOnExpand(false);
        /*
         * irrelevant code, only changes the shape and color of the scrollBar
         *
        JScrollBar sb = getVerticalScrollBar();
        sb.setUI(new ScrollBarColorUI(palette));
        sb = getHorizontalScrollBar();
        sb.setUI(new ScrollBarColorUI(palette));
         */
        addComponentListener(new resizeListener());
    }

    /*
     * listener to try to fix my problem resizing.
     */
    class resizeListener extends ComponentAdapter {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            //Recalculate the variable you mentioned
            /*
            System.out.println("I'm on resizeListener");
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();
            System.out.println("srollpane w: " + width + " scrollpane h: " + height);
            System.out.println("content w: " + content.getWidth() + " content h: " + content.getHeight());
            content.setSize(width, height);
            content.getParent().setSize(width, height);
            //content.revalidate();
            System.out.println("content w: " + content.getWidth() + " content h: " + content.getHeight());
            content.repaint();
            */
        }
    }
}
```

***MessageFor*** a JPanel with the message for x, with the colors of the background and palette. This JPanel it's add to the ScrollPaneColor a lot of times and we need the vertical scroll to continue reading it.

```
package view;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

/**
 * Define a <code>JPanel</code> with:
 * 
 *   * NORTH: <code>JPanel</code> panelNorth with BorderLayout:
 *      * CENTER: JLabel With date.
 *      * WEST: <code>JPanel</code> for Margin.
 *   * CENTER: <code>TextArea</code> with message for.
 *   * WEST: <code>JPanel</code> for Margin.
 * 
 * @author Jorge Dacal Cantos
 */
public class MessageFor extends JPanel {

    JLabel labelDate;

    /**
     * Create a <code>JPanel</code> with the message for, with the colors
     * of the background and palette.
     * 
     * @form message  Message to show.
     * @form background  Background color of the panel.
     * @form palette  Colors for the message.
     * @author Jorge Dacal Cantos
     */
    public MessageFor(String message, Color background, PaletteColor palette) {
        setBorder(new LineBorder(background, 10));
        setBackground(background);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JTextArea textAreaMensaje = new JTextArea(message);
        textAreaMensaje.setColumns(40);
        textAreaMensaje.setLineWrap(true);
        BevelBorder borderTextExterior = new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, palette.getAclaradoNv2(), palette.getAclaradoNv2(), palette.getEstandar(), palette.getEstandar());
        LineBorder borderTextInterior = new LineBorder(palette.getAclaradoNv1(), 10, true);
        textAreaMensaje.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(borderTextExterior, borderTextInterior));
        textAreaMensaje.setEditable(false);
        textAreaMensaje.setBackground(palette.getAclaradoNv1());
        textAreaMensaje.setForeground(palette.getTextoEnAclarado());
        textAreaMensaje.setSelectedTextColor(palette.getTextoEnEstandar());
        textAreaMensaje.setSelectionColor(palette.getEstandar());
        add(textAreaMensaje);

        JPanel panelMarginWest = new JPanel();
        FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) panelMarginWest.getLayout();
        flowLayout.setHgap(25);
        panelMarginWest.setBackground(background);
        add(panelMarginWest, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel panelNorth = new JPanel();
        add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panelNorth.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JPanel panelDate = new JPanel();
        panelNorth.add(panelDate);
        panelDate.setBackground(background);
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String DateWithFormat = formato.format(date.getTime());
        panelDate.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        labelDate = new JLabel(DateWithFormat);
        labelDate.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
        labelDate.setForeground(palette.getEstandar());
        panelDate.add(labelDate);

        JPanel panelMarginDate = new JPanel();
        panelMarginDate.setBackground(background);
        panelNorth.add(panelMarginDate, BorderLayout.WEST);
        panelMarginDate.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 25, 5));
    }

    /**
     * to add name next the date.
     * 
     * @form name  Name to show with the Date.
     */
    public void especificarname(String name){
        name = labelDate.getText() + " - for " + name;
        labelDate.setText(name);
    }
}
```

***PaletteColor*** only to decorate but need it to try it

```
/*
 * Nothing important on this class, its only to use different colors
 * to decorate.
 * 
 * Sorry but all comments of this class are in spanish.
 */
package view;

import java.awt.Color;

/**
 * Define como es una palette de colores para usares en la aplicacion.
 * 
 * Esta palette se compone de un color estandar, 3 versiones de este aclaradas
 * y 2 versiones oscurecidas, tambien como debe ser el texto sobre el color
 * estandar, las aclaradas y las oscurecidas
 * 
 * @author Jorge Dacal Cantos
 *
 */
public class PaletteColor {
    private Color estandar;
    private Color aclaradoNv1;
    private Color aclaradoNv2;
    private Color aclaradoNv3;
    private Color oscurecidoNv1;
    private Color oscurecidoNv2;
    private Color textoEnEstandar;
    private Color textoEnAclarado;
    private Color textoEnOscurecido;

    /**
     * Genera una palette de colores.
     * 
     * @param estandar  <code>Color</code> con tono estandar.
     * @param aclaradoNv1  <code>Color</code> con tono aclarado.
     * @param aclaradoNv2  <code>Color</code> con tono más aclarado.
     * @param aclaradoNv3  <code>Color</code> con tono aclarado al maximo.
     * @param oscurecidoNv1  <code>Color</code> con tono oscurecido.
     * @param oscurecidoNv2  <code>Color</code> con tono más oscurecido.
     */
    public PaletteColor(Color estandar, Color aclaradoNv1, Color aclaradoNv2,
            Color aclaradoNv3, Color oscurecidoNv1, Color oscurecidoNv2,
            Color textoEnEstandar, Color textoEnAclarado, Color textoEnOscurecido) {
        super();
        this.estandar = estandar;
        this.aclaradoNv1 = aclaradoNv1;
        this.aclaradoNv2 = aclaradoNv2;
        this.aclaradoNv3 = aclaradoNv3;
        this.oscurecidoNv1 = oscurecidoNv1;
        this.oscurecidoNv2 = oscurecidoNv2;
        this.textoEnEstandar = textoEnEstandar;
        this.textoEnAclarado = textoEnAclarado;
        this.textoEnOscurecido = textoEnOscurecido;
    }

    /**
     * @return estandar  El color estandar de la palette.
     */
    public Color getEstandar() {
        return estandar;
    }

    /**
     * @return aclaradoNv1  El color aclarado de la palette.
     */
    public Color getAclaradoNv1() {
        return aclaradoNv1;
    }

    /**
     * @return aclaradoNv2  El color más aclarado de la palette.
     */
    public Color getAclaradoNv2() {
        return aclaradoNv2;
    }

    /**
     * @return aclaradoNv3  El color aclarado al maximo de la palette.
     */
    public Color getAclaradoNv3() {
        return aclaradoNv3;
    }

    /**
     * @return oscurecidoNv1  El color oscurecido de la palette.
     */
    public Color getOscurecidoNv1() {
        return oscurecidoNv1;
    }

    /**
     * @return oscurecidoNv2  El color más oscurecido de la palette.
     */
    public Color getOscurecidoNv2() {
        return oscurecidoNv2;
    }

    /**
     * @return textoEnEstandar  el color que debe tener el texto sobre el color estandar.
     */
    public Color getTextoEnEstandar() {
        return textoEnEstandar;
    }

    /**
     * @return textoEnAclarado  el color que debe tener el texto sobre los colores aclarados.
     */
    public Color getTextoEnAclarado() {
        return textoEnAclarado;
    }

    /**
     * @return textoEnOscurecido  el color que debe tener el texto sobre los colores oscurecidos.
     */
    public Color getTextoEnOscurecido() {
        return textoEnOscurecido;
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me, because I already don't know what else to try. I've read many things here and on the Internet, and nothing has solved me.

Sorry for the length of my question and thank you very much everyone.

Best regards, Jorge